# How does this part of the FAQ apply to questions asked on ELL?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-faq

In the [FAQ](https://ell.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), there is a part about the questions that should not be asked, and which says:

> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: "I use `______` for `______`, what do you use?"

Does that mean that every subjective questions, where the OP provide what s/he think an answer in the question itself should be avoided?

I imagine those questions could be seen as polls (e.g. "I think it is so; do you think the same as me?") but I can also imagine questions where the OP asks about using a phrase, for which its usage is subjective, and for which the OP provide what it is a possible phrase, maybe because s/he has doubt about that phrase.

Vice versa, I can imagine a non subjective question similar to "What is the category of this word in the following sentence?" for which the OP says which category s/he think applicable to the word (without saying why), and s/he is right.

How does this part of the FAQ apply to questions asked on ELL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually have seen fewer questions of the sort the FAQ describes than I expected: our questioners have mostly been pretty good about describing actual problems ("I said this, but my friend/teacher/grammar book said it's wrong"), and when we do get an "I say this, what do you say?" it generally means something more like "I understand I should say this, but does it always work?" In SO terms, it's "I'm using this algorithm/tool/approach and it's worked so far, but what difficulties may I be creating for myself?"

The questions you describe seem to me to be of a different sort: "I think I've got this construction (or word, or parsing) right, can you confirm it?" That sort of question is routinely slammed on ELU with a "What makes you think there's anything wrong with it?"; but here, I think, a different response is called for. We **know** why the askers think there might be something wrong: because they don't have enough familiarity with the language to know. We're not being asked for interesting alternatives; we're being asked for expert **judgments**.

I think the proper response is

- If the asker's got it right, **a)** confirm that it's right, **b)** reinforce the lesson by providing additional examples, and **c)** expand the lesson by pointing out limitations--instances where the word or construction can't be used, or the parsing may be misapplied.
- if the asker's got it wrong, **a)** figure out where the misunderstanding came from ...

  - This, by the way, is **very difficult** for native speakers, who mostly have never had to consciously *learn* many points which arise here. It's hard to think of the air you breathe as something alien and frightening ...

  **b)** explain the misunderstanding and show how the situation in question differs from the assumptions the asker has brought to it, **c)** give a correct answer, with appropriate analysis, and **d)** drive the lesson home with additional examples.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think your conclusion applies to that FAQ entry.

That FAQ bullet simply means that you shouldn't ask questions that you might ask of a general support group. For example:

- *"When I get stuck for a word, I use book {X}. What do you use?"*
- *"I still have trouble understanding {X}. What was your most difficult-to-understand concept in English?"*

But when an author is simply providing "what s/he think an answer is in the question itself", that's simply showing prior effort and research. That's a good thing. It helps other users understand what has already been tried, and what further information (specifically) will help the original author.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that "use" has a slightly different meaning with "I use "Hello" in formal situations", compared to "I use "Emacs/vi" when programming". This may be slightly confusing to non-native speakers.

I think it should be edited to something less ambiguous, such as "I look up {X} when checking the spelling of the word, what book do you use?".